# Howto add a connector to rest-service-component

Tags: rest, mule

In my Mule 2.X configuration I need to post a message as a URL parameter. Therefore I created a service that has an inbound and then tries to send the message using `rest-service-component`, as follows:

```
<service name="myService">
    <inbound>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="path/inbound" synchronous="true" connector-ref="myVmConnector"/>
    </inbound>
    <http:rest-service-component serviceUrl="http://www.domain.com/path/insert.asp" httpMethod="POST">
        <http:payloadParameterName value="data_xml"/>
    </http:rest-service-component>
</service>
```

But when I process a message through it I receive the following information:

```
Message               : There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "http", so the connector to use must be specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
Type                  : org.mule.transport.service.TransportFactoryException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
http://www.mulesource.org/docs/site/current2/apidocs/org/mule/transport/service/TransportFactoryException.html
```

Normally this error can occur when you have multiple HTTP connectors configured and then you need to specify the connector on the endpoint (`connector-ref`). But the `rest-service-component` does not have such an attribute or child elements (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/HTTP+Transport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very old bug that remained unresolved:

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-4272

Try to use http:outbound-endpoint instead.

UPDATE:

Try using a Groovy script component in place of the rest component to create calls to dynamic URLs in Mule 2. Something like this might work:

```
eventContext.sendEvent(message,"http://www.domain.com/path/insert.asp?data_xml=${payload}")
```

Depending on your payload, you may also have to URL encode that.

Comment: How would you propose to do this in a http:outbound-endpoint?

Comment: Basic Mule 2 outbound syntax is <outbound><pass-through-router><http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081" /></pass-through-router></outbound>. I'm sorry, I don't have Mule 2 installed and my memories of the syntax are pretty vague.

Comment: But if I do a standard outbound like you say now, the payload is send as body of the HTTP POST. This won't work, because the partner is expecting to get the XML data into a URL parameter 'data_xml'. So this won't work...

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion for creating the URL string dynamically. I don't know if this works as you hope or if there are better options, but you can try it.

Comment: Indeed I tried with a Groovy component.. That solution worked. I did need to URLEncode the payload.